# Copying Named range Graph into powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, named-ranges

I am coding up a macro enable powerpoint presentation, the problem I am having is that I am trying to copy a named range (which is a graph) from an excel sheet, into a power point presentation.

```
  Dim xlApp As Object
  Dim xlWorkBook As Object
  Dim path As String
  Dim filename As String

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
  Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation

  path = "path"
  filename = "name.xlsx"

 Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path & filename)
 Set positionsheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Graphs")


'problem is in the below line
positionsheet.Range("Graph1").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture 
Set osh = PPPres.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

'adjust size here...

With xlWorkBook
 .Save
 .Close
End With

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
```

The error I receive is

> runtime error 1004, object-defined error

I have tried:

```
  positionsheet.Range("Graph1").Select
```

in front of the problem line...with no success.

Comment: Can we only copy in ranges such as .Range("A1:P20")? Really? there must be a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Range with Shapes, like this:

```
positionsheet.Shapes("Graph1")...
```

You must make sure that you've got the right name. It is not the same as the range, but it will show in the same box as the range names does.

Comment: I am copying quite a few graphs, do you think its necessary to clear power points clipboard?

Comment: Only if you notice a problem.